# "Class is not a template"

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

**Context**: I've got a class `Node` like this:

```
    #ifndef NODE_H_
    #define NODE_H_

    template <class T>
    class Node
    {
    private:
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;

      public:
        Node();
        Node(T);
        ~Node();    
   };    
    #endif /* NODE_H_ */
```

And a class `ListDE` like this:

```
/*
 * ListDE.h
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 22, 2013
 *      Author: x
 */

#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>

class ListDE
{
  private:
    int qElements;
    Node<T>* start;

    Node<T>* getNextNode(Node<T>* aNode);

  public:
    ListDE();
    ~ListDE();

    Node<T> getFirstPosition();
    int getQNodes();
    void setQNnodes(int q);
    Node<T>* getNode(int pos);

    T get_data(int pos);
    void change_value(int pos, T newValue);
    void add_new_data(T data);
    void concat(ListDE<T>* otherList);
    void delete_last();

};

#endif /* LIST_H_ */
```

**Problem**: when I try to compile, I get these errors:

```
ListDE.h:24:5: error: ‘Node’ is not a template
ListDE.h:26:5: error: ‘Node’ is not a template
ListDE.h:26:34: error: ‘Node’ is not a template
ListDE.h:32:5: error: ‘Node’ is not a template
ListDE.h:35:5: error: ‘Node’ is not a template
```

Can anyone explain to me what these mean? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds backwards but putting your constructor implementations in a .cpp file might be the issue. Depends on how you handled your templates. In general templated function defs go in the header.

Comment: i think you will have to give `template parameters` to every `NODE` variable as well as `LISTDE` variables as one or more node variable are defined within the LISTDE class

Comment: @thunderbird, I don't quite understand what you mean :S

Comment: Post your *actual* `ListDE.h` - The errors start at line 24, the code you've posted has less lines than this.

Comment: List.h or ListDE.h? your code here shows no error, please post detailed information.

Comment: @l19 i misread your code in a hurry...the only thing i think might be wrong is your header file extension '.h' try changing the extension to `.tcc'

Comment: `T new Value` ... that's not going to work. Please provide a minimal example, i.e. delete everything not necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @doomster, oops, that was a typo :P

Comment: @thunderbird: The compiler shouldn't care what extension a header file has.

Comment: These two files seem correct. Have you accidentally included some other definition of `Node` within c or cpp file ?

Comment: @silvesthu, there is in fact another file called "Node.h" somewhere else, but it is not in the same folder.

Comment: But is that other file in the include path? Can you include if as "Node.h" or to you need to specify "OtherFolder/Node.h"?

Comment: Only few people here like to "guess" answers. That's why you shouldn't expect an answer unless you provide a short, self contained, correct example (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I tried in the MSVC++ 2010, and i do not get any such error.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to Node.h

```
#error Found the right Node.h
```

Then, adjust your include paths until you hit that error.

Finally, comment it out again.